# R plotly height calculation for horizontal dot charts

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I routinely use R `plotly` to draw Bill Cleveland-style horizontal dot charts.  The category names are written in the left margin.  I have widely varying numbers of categories and wish for charts with a small number of categories (down to only one category) to be as short as possible and not have vertical scrolling on the legend that appears in the right margin.  I've experiment with a number of algorithms for computing the `height` needed in the `plotly::plot_ly()` call, and have it working pretty well when the number of categories is large.  But not so well for a small number.  Here is one attempt:

```
heightDotchart = function(rows, per=25, low=200, high=800)
     min(high, max(low, per * rows))
```

I found that if I set the lower limit for `height` to 300 nothing is ever hidden, but the 1- or 2-category situation wastes too much vertical space.

I would especially like to compute `height` automatically so as to have the minimum height without omitting points on the plot and without having any labels colliding.

Ii understand that the `plotly` `layout` parameter `autosize` results in larger graphic areas than needed.